# Как обновить страницу не перезагружая ее

Tags: loading, javascript

Я в Javascript полный ноль.

У меня такая задача. обновить страницу не перезагружая ее.

Например настранице есть Messages (0) и нужно если пришло письмо поменять значение 0 на пример 2. или вариант такой добавить результат формы в базу данных.

Вообщем основная задача выташить или запихать в базу инфу без перезагрузки страницы.

Как я понял вставить можно методом загрузки второго файла типа router.php. А вот как выташить и поменять инфу вообще понятия не имею.

Cам метод вставки и вытаскивания методами из базы данных через php.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Comment: > Я в Javascript полный ноль.

этой фразой вы отбиваете охоту вам помогать. если вы полный 0, то зачем вы вообще беретесь за задачу ? А если хотите выучить, так сначала выучите основы, а потом задавайте вопрос по существу, с вашим кодом, который не работает

Comment: дело в том, что я сейчас разбироюсь c php, а сразу с двумя языками каша получится. Синтаксис я понимаю просто т.е. вставить скрипт подкоректировать его я могу. Но вот полность его написать немогу и я не прошу мне написать полный скрипт. Мне надо узнать куда копать. Если с самим скриптом я разобрался, я немогу разобраться как динамически вытаскивать инфу из одного файла и вставлять ее в другой без перезагрузки. (Как я понимаю это так можно реализовать, задачу выше)

PS! взялся для удобства работы (Дом. хобби) Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [на этом сайте](http://ruseller.com/project.php?id=7) есть подробные уроки по JavaScript - Ajax.

Удачи в изучении материала :)

Comment: ok, скачал глазею